# REDHAWK-SDR unable to play audio via python using SoundSink

Tags: redhawksdr

Attempting to play a signal through computer speakers via python so I tried the example in [7.1](https://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainch7.html) of the manual.  I see the signal on the plot but hear nothing over the speakers.  Is SoundSink the wrong approach for this?  I'm running REDHAWK 2.0.6 on CentOS 7.  In case this is important, the first time sb.start() is called, "shared memfd open() failed: Invalid argument" is displayed.  When called a second time that message doesn't appear.  I am able to play audio from within the REDHAWK IDE.

```
from ossie.utils import sb
import frontend
sim = sb.launch("rh.FmRdsSimulator")
demod=sb.launch("rh.AmFmPmBasebandDemod")
filter=sb.launch("rh.fastfilter")
resample=sb.launch("rh.ArbitraryRateResampler")
agc=sb.launch("rh.agc")
sink=sb.SoundSink()
plot=sb.Plot()
sim.connect(demod)
demod.connect(filter, usesPortName="fm_dataFloat_out")
filter.connect(resample)
resample.connect(agc)
agc.connect(sink)
agc.connect(plot)
sim.addAWGN=False
demod.freqDeviation=15000.0
filter.filterProps.freq1=16000.0
filter.filterProps.Ripple=0.5
filter.filterProps.Type="lowpass"
resample.outputRate=32000.0
sb.start()
alloc = frontend.createTunerAllocation(
    "RX_DIGITIZER", 
    allocation_id="testing", 
    center_frequency=100.1e6, 
    sample_rate=256e3,
    sample_rate_tolerance=20.0)
sim.allocateCapacity(alloc)
```

Answer (score 0):

The package that SoundSink uses to generate sound has been deprecated in CentOS 7 (but is still available in CentOS 6). This issue has been added to the backlog and will be fixed in a future release.